# Obtener valores de un checkbox de un Fomulario Reactivo

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

Estoy implementando un Formulario Reactivo, pero tengo un problema al obtener los valores del `checkbox`, solo me aparece el valor del primer del valor que selecciono y no los demás.

Adjunto mi código:

***Componente.ts***

```
  registerForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(
    private Restservice: RestserviceService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      texto: [""],
      checkArray: [""],
      radiobutton: [""],
      matriz: [""],
      lista: [""],
      archivo: [""],
      fecha: [""],
      numerico: [""],
      Datocomun: [""],
    });
  }

//Muestro los valores del Formulario
 submit() {
    if (this.registerForm.valid) {
      console.log("completo ", this.registerForm.value);
      // this.crearRespuestas();
    } else {
      alert("FILL ALL FIELDS");
    }
  }
```

Aquí uso el p-checkbo de primeng pero el problema es que solo me reconoce el primer valor seleccionado y los demás no

Html.

```
<div *ngIf="p.codigo_tipopreguntas == 2">
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let v of valores; let i=index">
                              <div *ngIf="p.id === v.codigo_pregunta">
                                  <p-checkbox  value="{{v.preguntas_valor}}"
                                    label="{{v.preguntas_valor}}" formControlName="checkbox"></p-checkbox>
                              </div>
                            </ng-container>
                          </div>

 <button class="btn btn-info btn-just-icon btn-round btn-link" pTooltip="Guardar" tooltipPosition="top"
              (click)="submit()">
              <i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i>
            </button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin tener todo el codigo disponible es dificil poder darle una respuesta completamente terminada pero lo que puedo observar usted debe cambiar

```
...
<p-checkbox  value="{{v.preguntas_valor}}" label="{{v.preguntas_valor}}" formControlName="checkbox"></p-checkbox>
...
```

por

```
<!-- Correcto -->
<p-checkbox [formControl]="registerForm.controls['checkboxes']"  label="{{v.preguntas_valor}}"></p-checkbox>
```

Espero esta solucion le ayude a resolver el problema.